# React: Disconnecting firebase ref on componentWillUnMount

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to disconnect the firebase ref when the user changes the view in a single page application. When said user changes view I want to get a new ref to firebase, as I only want filtered data and each view filters different data.

The problem arises when I change the view and update some data. Then react fires the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op.

This error references the **other view** as it tries to update an unmounted component. This *shouldn't* happen because **I close the ref on componentWillUnMount**.

In both views I have the following code for getting a new ref:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // I have declared this.ref on the constructor so I can call off() on componentWillUnMount
    this.ref = firebase.database().ref().child('mainNode').orderByChild('someProperty').equalTo('someValue');

    this.ref.on('value', (snap) => {
      let values = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        let value = child.val();
        let key = child.key;
        const valueWithKey = update(value, {$merge: {key}});
        values.push(valueWithKey);
      });
      // This is the offending line
      this.setState({data: values});
    });
  }
```

And here is my componentWillUnMount code:

```
componentWillUnMount() {
    this.ref.off();
    // I have also tried goOffline()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out the correct lifecycle hook is named `componentWillUnmount` and not `componentWillUnMount`, that was causing React to not execute the function.